# Backbone Views and Subviews on router change

Tags: backbone.js, view

I don't have too much experience with Backbone.js, so please excuse my ignorance if I've completely missed something here.

I have an app that has a sidebar which is linked to a Router object, when the user clicks one of the links I send a `navigate` event. But that's not useful on its own.

What I have is a static sidebar on the left, then a `.pane` element on the right. The `.pane` is just a wrapper for what will be dynamically loaded content. I've made this its own view, but what I need to do is add a sub view into it when the user clicks on a link in the sidebar.

```
|--------------------------------------- |
| Link | |-----------------------------| |
| Link | |.pane                        | |
| Link | |                             | |
| Link | |                             | |
| Link | |                             | |
| Link | |-----------------------------| |
|--------------------------------------- |
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi James, it is hard to answer your question without knowing how your app is constructed.  If you post some code I would be happy to help.  Since you are new to backbone you may find a backbone framework or boilerplate a good place to start since they are a bit more opinionated than vanilla backbone:    
https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette 
https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate

Comment: There isn't much to see, but [here is a link](http://jsbin.com/etumab/1) with the JS code so far. You can access the links with `#find/` etc.

Comment: So... why don't you just wrap your left sidebar in a view and listen to clicks? Also, for the right one, why don't you use anchor elements? Backbone's Router listens to hash changes, it doesn't require you to use the `navigate` method.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how that works @Loamhoof?

Comment: @James for which part? That's just basic use of Backbone I'd say. You should look for some tutorial (although if I think about those I saw, I know no good one to give you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should load a view with the nav bar on the index state.
Then, each link wil change the url. For each url, set a router state, wich calls another view for each menu item.
If you still don't get the idea, you should watch some backbone tutorials mate.
You can find some on:
http://www.tutsplus.com
http://www.backbonetutorials.com

Hope it helps